# phpMyAdmin hangs on proc with multiple SELECTS

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, freeze, multiple-resultsets

When I `CALL` this proc in MySQL, it just shows `LOADING...` and even freezes my server:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(IN index1 INT, IN count1 INT, IN index2 INT, IN count2 INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id FROM view1 WHERE column1 IS NULL OR column1 = 1 ORDER BY dateColumn DESC LIMIT index1, count1;
    SELECT id FROM view1 WHERE column2 = 0 ORDER BY column3 DESC LIMIT index2, count2;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

If I only have one of either `SELECT`s, it works.

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing/doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

**Details**

I'm creating a proc for PHP so that I don't have to make so many connections to the database.  Each `SELECT` needs to be its' own result set with column information for ease in PHP.

I need the slightly extra speed because my site is heavily dependent upon dynamic pagination.

Comment: Not sure why it would hang, but you probably want a union between the two selects to get a single result set

Comment: you can also try 
Set @someVar := (select .....)

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks for looking!  Yeah, I pretty much ripped it out of the docs, so I have no idea what gives.  As for `UNION`, the n+1 result sets don't have column names, right?

Comment: @SureshKamrushi I appreciate your time!  Do I return `@someVar`?  MySQL obviously isn't my strong suit.  ;P

Comment: Not sure how that works in MySQL, I use SQL/Server more which from memory keeps the column names OK (if they are the same)

Comment: @PeterJ Yeah, thought that was the case.  This sucker will end up having like 6 individual `SELECT`s by the time I'm done, and I need them to keep their column names for ease in PHP, so this is the best I can come up with now.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy Try to run this two query seperately and find how much time have been taken by both queries?

Comment: @SaharshShah They both come back "instantly", by themselves or in the proc.  It's just when they're together, something goes wrong.  I'm doing it this crazy way because I need the 10s of ms that's wasted in constantly opening and closing database connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is quite sensible.  This looks like a defect in phpmyadmin that may have been recently fixed, where stored procedures returning multiple result sets were not handled properly.

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=377408&aid=3474853&group_id=23067

Comment: Thank-you Michael.  I have 3.5.1.  Do I need to upgrade?

Comment: Just upgraded to latest.  Still hanging.  Jeez, this is ridiculous.  Thanks for your help! (and the upgrade)

Comment: For the record, the first selection (Adminer) here http://www.webdesigneronline.co.uk/10-great-alternatives-to-phpmyadmin worked.

Comment: There have been a few releases since 3.5.1 but it's hard to tell from the release notes whether that fix has been pushed into any of them.  I always test multi-result-set SPs with the mysql command line client, because it handles them flawlessly, so that would be my recommendation for a guaranteed solution.

Comment: The fix for this bug is in the master branch of phpMyAdmin at the moment. Which means that it will be available in version 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(IN index1 INT, IN count1 INT, IN index2 INT, IN count2 INT)
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT id FROM view1 WHERE column1 IS NULL OR column1 = 1 ORDER BY dateColumn DESC LIMIT ', index1, ', ', count1);
    SET @s1 = CONCAT('SELECT id FROM view1 WHERE column2 = 0 ORDER BY column3 DESC LIMIT ', index2, ', ', count2);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank-you very much for trying!  For some reason, it gives `#1064` at `@index1` for the first proc.  The second proc takes, but it gives the same result as my original.  Ugh!  Is there some setting that I have to turn on to allow multiple result sets in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Oh!  I misread!  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@index1, @count1; SELECT id FROM view1' at line 12`  Is `LIMIT` with index AND count forbidden in MySQL stored proc?

Comment: I am removing my first query and want to know what is the issue in second query

Comment: I think this might be it: http://dbaspot.com/mysql/378711-stored-procedure-problem-variable-limit.html

Comment: The proc you have left gives no error, but when I `CALL`, it hangs just as my original.  Need to find a another program to test with...